# How to use LDAP Authentication in a corporate environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'd like users to log into my Spring-Boot application with their corporate username/password-combination (so I can use AD authentication and (maybe also) use that AD to query active users).

So I did `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.MY.DOMAIN` which resulted in the outcome:

```
Server: Servername.MY.DOMAIN
Address: 1.1.1.1

_ldap._tcp.MY.DOMAIN       SRV service location
      priority             = 0
      weight               = 50
      port                 = 389
      svr hostname         = a_host.MY.DOMAIN
//... a few more of these
a_host.MY.DOMAIN  internet address = 5.5.5.5
```

Then I used this VBS:

```
set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
wscript.echo "DN: " & objUser.distinguishedName
```

that returned:

```
DN: CN=Lastname\, Firstname,OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN
```

and now I tried (as suggested in the first answer) to configure my Spring Boot application using [this class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) for that login refering to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077160/ldap-authentication-in-spring-boot-app/47085504#47085504):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/secure")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("MY.COMPANY", "ldap://a_host.MY.DOMAIN:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Sadly when I start the application and insert my company credentials into my Spring-Boot-Security-Login-UI, I can not login to the application. Also, the path `/secure` is not accessible via `http://localhost:8080/secure` (results in 404). Now when I enable debugging for Spring-Boot-Security I get the following output on inserting my credentials:

```
2018-12-17 11:47:12.793 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:16.510 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.462 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@28db75a9. A new one will be created.
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@28db75a9. A new one will be created.
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
2018-12-17 11:47:27.466 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
2018-12-17 11:47:27.470 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-12-17 11:47:27.470 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-12-17 11:47:27.534 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User '%my_user%' not found
2018-12-17 11:47:27.534 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User '%my_user%' not found
2018-12-17 11:47:27.534 DEBUG 13232 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Ung³ltige Anmeldedaten

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Ung³ltige Anmeldedaten
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:151) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
//...
2018-12-17 11:47:27.538 DEBUG 13232 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Ung³ltige Anmeldedaten
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Ung³ltige Anmeldedaten
```

So as he is not finding my User (I also tried with Username@DOMAIN, DOMAIN\username ...) it seems like I either missconfigured the `url` or used the wrong form to insert my login-data (I used the startup page when launching the application with `Spring-Boot-Security`).

**UPDATE:**

I ensured that the provided username %my_user% is equal to my UPN, so it seems to be a configuration problem, since spring boot security says that it cannot be found.

**UPDATE2:**

I am going to update this post to the very final solution we came to thanks to @GabrielLuci . The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation shows the configuration to use on a.... "normal" LDAP directory (like say OpenLDAP). Active Directory has its own quirks, so it doesn't quite behave the same way as the rest of the LDAP world.

Spring does have an [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) class just for this purpose. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085504/1202807) has an example of how to make use of it in your `WebSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/secure")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("adldap.company.com", "ldap://adldap.company.com");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to change my configuration and updated my quesion :)

Comment: I'm having troubles determining what my `url` should look like. At the moment I picked out the first entry I got from that `nslookup` command (the computer name) and did the following: `ldap://computername.my.domain:389` - without providing and OC or something like that. Is that right?

Comment: Just `ldap://my.domain` should be fine (you could specify the "computername" of a domain controller, but there is no need to. Also, the default port for LDAP is 389, so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) says that the search filter defaults to using the `userPrincipalName` (usually `username@domain.com`). If you want to change that to use the regular username (`sAMAccountName`), you can call `provider.setSearchFilter()`. I updated my code with that.

Comment: Sadly the outcome is the same - Alright, I never thought about this, but let me try to explain what I want to do: In our corporation we log in to e.g. Outlook with Shorthand & Password-combination. Also, these Shorthands are mapped to Mail-Adresses (shorthand@company.com) - now, what is the userPrincipleName? According to the documentation it seems to be the AD-CN? My Script i execute in my post tells me as CN `lastname,\ firstname`, shouldn't that be the Shorthand I use for authentication (or want to use)?

Comment: `userPrincipalName` is the name of the actual attribute in AD. If you look at a user in AD Users and Computers, on the Account tab, it's the "User logon name" at the top (it's split into two parts in that window). It can be equal to the email address, but it doesn't have to be. (although if you are using Office 365, it does have to equal the email address)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185361/discussion-between-gabriel-luci-and-rudiger).