# how to authenticate a user in LDAP with credentials in basic auth header using spring boot and spring secuirty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

i am trying to implement spring security in spring boot application.I am trying to get credentials over a basic auth request header and with those credentials invoking spring security LDAP authentication.whats the best approach to achieve it? Am trying to add a higher-order filter and parsing the header for credentials and invoke it as a dependency in class extending websecurityconfigureradapter class.

Comment: Did you succeed? You can show us what you have attempted to make it work, or the solution if your found one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077160/ldap-authentication-in-spring-boot-app This question lead me to the way.